# Assertion.h in FreeBSD

Tags: c, list, freebsd, assertion

I am trying to change the kernel of the freebsd and I need to use the library `list.h` which is in the directory: `/usr/src/lib/libc/include/isc`. There are two lines in this file which make errors:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <isc/assertion.h>
```

I could find the file `assert.h` and put it in the directory but I couldn't find `assertion.h` file on the net. Is there any link for downloading this library?

Comment: http://www.filewatcher.com/p/src.tgz.62567380/usr/src/lib/libc/include/isc/assertions.h.html

Comment: maybe what you are trying to do is not the solution you need; usually adding header files adds other dependencies which are solved by adding other header files and it quickly becomes painful. So, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use /usr/src/lib/libc/include/isc in the kernel. This is part of the user space libc, same goes for assert.h.

You can use the `sys/queue.h` file if you need linked lists, see e.g. [here](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/geom-class/kernelprog.html)

For assertions in the kernel, use the [KASSERT](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/9/KASSERT/)() macro.